# VPS randomly rejects networks

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

I am running a couple of vps with different hosting companies. One of our servers is causing a lot of trouble lately by randomly rejecting certain networks (office, home, mobile hotspots) from accessing the server. Some days it is working without any problems, the other day it is completely blocked. I also have a dedicated server monitor which tells me that all services are reachable and online. Pinging is still working but accessing via SSH, Port 80 etc. is rejected immediately. I am running fail2ban but I don't see any blocked ip addresses in the logs. So my assumption is that this issue is caused by my iptables ruleset.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request ctstate NEW
UDP        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
TCP        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN ctstate NEW
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             recent: SET name: TCP-PORTSCAN side: source reject-with tcp-reset
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             recent: SET name: UDP-PORTSCAN side: source reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain TCP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 name: TCP-PORTSCAN side: source reject-with tcp-reset
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:921

Chain UDP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 name: UDP-PORTSCAN side: source reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Is there any rule that might cause this issues and why?

PS: 921 is my custom ssh port.

Comment: Try moving your portscan `recent` rule after your `http`, `https` and `921` rules, just to stop the blocking for now.  Then add a logging rule prior to the `UPDATE` rules so you can see what is triggering it.

Comment: The rule seems to be triggered by by owncloud/nextcloud application: "some web applications such as OwnCloud will open a new web connection for each file being sync'd, rather than pipelining them together in a single connection.In those circumstances for those applications you may need to bypass this for that one port. But, only bypass it for the port or ports you need for those specific applications, not for the entire server." How would I do this?